# Best way to check the null for combination of two object

Tags: c++, coding-style

I wanted to ask this question since long time. After spending some time I feel like not getting a proper way to check two objects for null together, so i am asking it.

For example : I have one function like this

```
int Function(Object* obj1, Object* obj2) 
{
   if(obj1 == null && obj2 == null)
   { 
       // Do someting........
   }
   else if(obj1 == null && obj2 != null)
   { 
       // Do something.....
   }
   else if(obj1 != null && obj2 == null)
   {
       // Do something......
   }
   else
   {
       // Do something........
   }
   return 0;
```

As we can see, we have too many if condition just to check the combination of two object for null.

Is there any other way to do it more effectively so that the readability is good?

Note : Object is a class and no operator is overloaded.

Comment: Your code is clear and readable to me.

Comment: `Object` being a class object or not isn't relevant here.

Comment: You can reduce branches by combining them, but this largely dependents on the actual code inside each block. And giving each nullptr test a name (makes them functions) is always a viable solution.

Comment: Do you have to accept nulls in your function? Maybe it would be better to forbid passing nullptr to this function (and throw something if that happens).

Comment: Your code is clear with detail if condition, it keeps the code easier to maintain and to debug. Put the most passed test in the first if condition to get better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform at most two comparisons.  This is how I would do it:

```
if( obj1 )
{
    if( obj2 )
    {
        // obj1 and obj2 are both valid.
    }
    else
    {
        // obj1 is valid, obj2 is nullptr.
    }
}
else
{
    if( obj2 )
    {
        // obj1 is nullptr, obj2 is valid.
    }
    else
    {
        // Both are nullptr.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The main idea is to reduce the number of *if...else* branches.
Maybe, some kind of dispatcher, something like that:

```
int ptr_pair_state(const obj1 *p1, const obj1 *p2)
{
    return (p1 ? 1 : 0) | (p2 ? 2 : 0);
}

int Function(Object* obj1, Object* obj2)
{
    std::map<int, std::function<void()>> disp{ { 0, f1 }, { 1, f2 }, { 2, f3 }, {3, f4 } };
    int state = ptr_pair_state(obj1, obj2);
    disp[state]();
}
```

where *f1 - f4* are some functions, for example

```
void f1()
{
    std::cout << "f1";
}
```

However, this may seem like an unnecessary complication, so another simple alternative - to use switch operator:

```
int Function(Object* obj1, Object* obj2)
{    
    int v = (p1 ? 1 : 0) | (p2 ? 2 : 0);
    switch(v)
    {
    case 0: // both nullptr
        break;
    case 1: // p1 not nullptr
        break;
    case 2: // p2 not nullptr
        break;
    case 3: // both not nullptr
        break;
    }
}
```

which much more elegant then endless *if...else if*